# Dealing with duplicates in a pandas query

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have the following DataFrame:

```
data = {'Customer_ID': ['123','2','1010','123'],
    'Date_Create': ['12/08/2010','04/10/1998','27/05/2010','12/08/2010'],
    'Purchase':[1,1,0,1]
    }

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Customer_ID', 'Date_Create','Purchase'])
```

I want to perform this query:

```
df_2 = df[['Customer_ID','Date_Create','Purchase']].groupby(['Customer_ID'], 
as_index=False).sum().sort_values(by='Purchase', ascending=False)
```

The objective of this query is to sum all purchases(boolean field) and as output a dataframe with 3 columns: `'Customer_ID', 'Date_Create','Purchase`

Problem is: the field `Date_Create` is not in query because it has duplicate as the date_creation of the account does not change.

How can i solve it?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add column `Date_Create` to `groupby` if same values per `Customer_ID`:

```
(df.groupby(['Customer_ID','Date_Create'], as_index=False)['Purchase']
   .sum()
   .sort_values(by='Purchase', ascending=False))
```

If not, use some aggregation function - e.g. [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) for first `date` per groups:

```
(df.groupby('Customer_ID')
   .agg(Purchase = ('Purchase', 'sum'), Date_Create= ('Date_Create', 'first'))
   .reset_index()
   .sort_values(by='Purchase', ascending=False))
```

Answer (score 2):

If im understanding it correctly and your source data has some duplicates,

There's a function specifically for this, `dataframe.drop_duplicates()`

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html

To only consider some columns in the duplicate check, use `subset`:

```
df2 = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Customer_ID','Date_Create'])
```